# Change the ArcMap background from white to blue (i.e the sea)

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, shapefile, color

Say I have an image like the map below, how can I change the white to blue, to represent that this is the ocean? It is not part of the shapefile itself, so I cannot use symbology.

[image]

Comment: If it is in fact over a body of water use a basemap

Answer (score 10, accepted):

In the Data Frame properties, click the Frame tab and change the background color:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

In TOC, right click Layer to open the Data Frame properties

in the Frame tab and change the background color

The toturial here: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=v2gKl8jWJuo

Comment: It is a bit pointless to post a duplicate answer of the already accepted one. If you want to add a link to a video it's maybe better to add it in a comment